# Push notification when tag is deleted

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

In Bluemix push notification, there may be multiple devices subscribe to a tag. When the tag is deleted from the server using REST API, what happens to the devices that are subscribed to the tag? Is there an automatic unsubscribe?

How to do the clean up?

Thanks.

Jen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**: No clean up is needed.

**Long Answer**: The subscriptions are maintained by the Push Notifications service Bluemix instance. When a tag is deleted, so is all the information with that tag, including subscribers. There is no automatic unsubscribe because the tag ceases to exist and no further action is needed from the client side.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Cariello